# How to take two time-based inputs from a user without calling wait() or yield()

Tags: java, input, time, mouse

I'm currently in the process of making a game in Java. I've recently been working on mouse input, and where I'm stuck has to do with the game recognizing when the mouse has moved. I've obviously gotten it to accept mouse input, but I can't make the in-game player rotate correctly based upon mouse position.

What I can come up with to fix it is to take a measurement of the mouse's x position at one point in time, and then compare it to another measurement one millisecond later to see whether or not the mouse has moved, and if so, to get the player to rotate linearly faster with the distance the mouse has translated.

*However, I have no idea how to do that without forcing the entire program to wait or yield (which would be bad).*

I've tried writing the position to a file and then re-reading it immediately after, but it tends to read from the file at different rates, causing the rotation to be spastic and uneven. But besides that, I'm open to ideas. I can't really post my code because there are many class files that go into the program, but if necessary, I can post the whole project to github for anyone to look at.

GitHub Repository link: https://github.com/isl1/Duplicity

**P.S. If it helps, I'm using LWJGL 3, paulscode, and Slick-Util on Eclipse Mars.**